# Implementing imclose(IM, SE) in opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I want to detect the background of the following image whose foreground is always lots of black dots:

**img.png**

[image]

Someone performs morphological closing on the image with disk-shaped structuring element and obtain a good result:

[image]

**Matlab code:**

```
img = imread('c:\img.png');
bg = imclose(img, strel('disk', 15));
figure('name', 'bg'), imshow(bg);
```

So how to implement imclose(IM, SE) in opencv to replace the work in MATLAB or there is another better way to detect such background using opencv method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cv::getStructuringElement()` to create an elliptical structuring element, and `cv::morphologyEx()` to perform a closing operation.

```
cv::morphologyEx(img, img, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(21,21)));
```

I had to modify the structuring element size slightly to produce similar results to your MATLAB example:

[image: Closed image]

Since you seem to be interested in morphological operations with OpenCV, I recommend you give the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html) a read-through to see what all it is capable of.

Comment: Nice to see you again. Thanks for your answer and recommendation