# How to group nearby contours in OpenCV Python? - Zebra Crossing detection

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, contour

I want to detect the zebra crossing lines. I have tried to find out the co-ordinates of zebra crossing line in the image using **contour** but it gives the output for the distinct white boxes (only white lines in the zebra crossing). But I need the co-ordinates of the entire zebra crossing.

Please let me know the way to group the contours or suggest me another method to detect zebra crossing.

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oABRR.jpg)

[Output image obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dGhx.jpg)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzu5H.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('d.jpg',-1)
paper = cv2.resize(image,(500,500))
ret, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(paper, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
                        200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    # convert all coordinates floating point values to int
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(paper, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0),1)
cv2.imshow('paper', paper)
cv2.imwrite('paper.jpg',paper)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [merge nearby contours](https://answers.opencv.org/question/204128/how-to-merge-nearby-rectangles/)?

Comment: Can you share the source image?

Comment: @coffeewin I have tried it, but the source image detects many contours along with the zebra crossing. So it merges the whole image and doesn't provide required output.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I have added the source image in the Description. Please check

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I want to detect the zebra crossing lines. I have added the expected output image in the Description. Please check. Thank you

Comment: An algorithm can be created but you can not expect it to work in every image. I  think training seems a better solution for this.

Comment: Try color thresholding on white using cv2.inRange(). Then use morphology to merge the regions in the binary image. Then get your contours.

Answer (score 4):

You can [closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)) morphological operation for closing the gaps.

I cat suggest the following stages:

- Find contours in `thresh_gray`.
- Erase contours with very small area (noise).
- Erase contours with low aspect ratio (assume zebra line must be long and narrow.
- Use [morphologyEx](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphologyex) to perform closing morphological operation - the closing merges close components.
- Find contours again in the image after erasing and closing.
  At the last stage, ignore small contours.

Here is a working code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('d.jpg', -1)
paper = cv2.resize(image, (500,500))
ret, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(paper, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Erase small contours, and contours which small aspect ratio (close to a square)
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)

    # Fill very small contours with zero (erase small contours).
    if area < 10:
        cv2.fillPoly(thresh_gray, pts=[c], color=0)
        continue

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247821/find-width-and-height-of-rotatedrect
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    (x, y), (w, h), angle = rect
    aspect_ratio = max(w, h) / min(w, h)

    # Assume zebra line must be long and narrow (long part must be at lease 1.5 times the narrow part).
    if (aspect_ratio < 1.5):
        cv2.fillPoly(thresh_gray, pts=[c], color=0)
        continue


# Use "close" morphological operation to close the gaps between contours
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339988/implementing-imcloseim-se-in-opencv
thresh_gray = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (51,51)));

# Find contours in thresh_gray after closing the gaps
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)

    # Small contours are ignored.
    if area < 500:
        cv2.fillPoly(thresh_gray, pts=[c], color=0)
        continue

    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    # convert all coordinates floating point values to int
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(paper, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0),1)

cv2.imshow('paper', paper)
cv2.imwrite('paper.jpg', paper)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`thresh_gray` before erasing small and squared contours:
[image]

`thresh_gray` after erasing small and squared contours:
[image]

`thresh_gray` after close operation:
[image]

Final result:
[image]

---

Remark:
I have some doubts about the benefit of using morphological operation for closing the gaps.
It might be better using a smart logic based on geometry instead.